# installed sphinx extension for mediawiki, everything seems working well, but just no search result

Tags: php, sphinx, mediawiki-extensions

I installed sphinx 2.2.10 in centos 7 ,mediawiki version is 1.22 , with the installation instruction in sphinxsearch extension [homepage](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SphinxSearch), I run the indexer command in step 3 successfully. But  there is no search command installed on my server and I can't test sphinx out. It seems that there isn't any installation directory of sphinx in centos. It just have a searchd and indexer in the system bin directory.Luckily, I can start the searchd daemon by server searchd start and it said it's listening on port 9312.  And I installed the extension and copied the php api correctly.But I can't get any result by search, there is a php warning shows in the page though, says some methods are deprecated, shouldn't be used.below are some of my searchd.log file:

```
Mon Mar  7 23:16:56.467 2016] [ 1737] shutdown complete
[Mon Mar  7 23:41:41.001 2016] [24720] watchdog: main process 24721 forked ok
[Mon Mar  7 23:41:41.006 2016] [24721] listening on 127.0.0.1:9312
[Mon Mar  7 23:41:41.379 2016] [24721] binlog: replaying log /var/data/binlog.001
[Mon Mar  7 23:41:41.380 2016] [24721] binlog: replay stats: 0 rows in 0 commits; 0 updates, 0         reconfigure; 0 indexes[Mon Mar  7 23:41:41.380 2016] [24721] binlog: finished replaying /var/data/binlog.001; 0.0 MB in 0.000 sec
[Mon Mar  7 23:41:41.380 2016] [24721] binlog: replaying log /var/data/binlog.001
[Mon Mar  7 23:41:41.380 2016] [24721] binlog: replay stats: 0 rows in 0 commits; 0 updates, 0 reconfigure; 0 indexes
[Mon Mar  7 23:41:41.380 2016] [24721] binlog: finished replaying /var/data/binlog.001; 0.0 MB in 0.000 sec[Mon Mar  7 23:41:41.380 2016] [24721] binlog: finished replaying total 2 in 0.000 sec
[Mon Mar  7 23:41:41.381 2016] [24721] accepting connections
```

Now I have no idea how to solve this problem and any suggestion or help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not got any result because my wiki is not written in english, but the default configuration file of mediawiki sphinxsearch extension has no charset table for other languages, so the result is empty.